# Show that $\lim_{y \rightarrow y_{0}}g(y)=L$ considering a constant $K>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ an interval such that $g:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $y_{0} \in I$.

Let's suppose that exists constants $K>0$ and $L$ such that $$|g(y)-L|\leq K|y-y_{0}|\qquad \forall y \in I$$

I want to  prove  that $$\lim_{y \rightarrow y_{0}}g(y)=L$$ considering this constant $K>0$.  But I have no idea where I must start. Should I use $\epsilon-\delta$ or not? What does the constant mean?

I would really appreciate suggestions, hints or anything to make it clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, do an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof.

Start by fixing $\varepsilon >0$.

Let $\delta>0$ be a number which we will fix later, and suppose $|y-y_0|<\delta$. Then
$$
|g(y)-L|\le K|y-y_0|<K\delta 
$$
Looking at the above, if we take $\delta:=\frac{\varepsilon}{K}$, it just so happens that
$$
|g(y)-L|<\varepsilon
$$
If  you read back, we've shown that whenever $|y-y_0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{K}$, we also have $|g(y)-L|<\varepsilon$. But then we're done!

Does this help?

Comment: Sure, thank you. I have couple of  questions about it, how to fix the limit to get $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}g(y)=L$$   ?, Does the constant $k>0$ has a special meaning or it is a simple constant?. Sometimes Real Analysis looks really tricky. Every single detail counts to success the proof.

Comment: Considering that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_{0}}g(y)=L$$    it's not clear because $x \rightarrow x_{0} $ but it seems that you have shown whenever $y \rightarrow y_{0} $

Comment: @Malu I assumed you had a typo and meant $y_0$ in the limit. Otherwise, this is false (and meaningless). The constant $K$ allows you to relate the decay of $|g(y)-L|$ to that of $|y-y_0|$, namely $|g(y)-L|$ goes to $0$ at most as fast at $K|y-y_0|$ does. This is stronger than simply saying $\lim_{y\to y_0} g(y)=L$, but weaker than, for example, $|g(y)-L|\le K|y-y_0|^2$ for every  $y\in I$.

Comment: I agree. It is a typo. You re right. Thank you. Sorry for that. My mistake.